# Socket.io Angular sending multiple data

Tags: angular, socket.io, nestjs

So, i have Socket.io client set up on Angular (Backend: NestJS), and when i try to connect to a server:

```
socket = io(`${environment.api_url}/message`);
```

Then i log out every new connections on the server side (`console.log('connected')`, then i get this:

```
connected
connected
connected
```

But its only with namespace message, on a different namespace that i use like `friends`, i get:

```
connected
```

Can you tell me why? Thanks

**My code: (i put it in a different link, bc stackoverflow wont let me do it otherwise.):**
https://cdn.chatenium.hu/CDN/stack/app.component.ts

https://cdn.chatenium.hu/CDN/stack/dm.component.ts

https://cdn.chatenium.hu/CDN/stack/message.component.ts

https://cdn.chatenium.hu/CDN/stack/message.controller.ts

https://cdn.chatenium.hu/CDN/stack/message.module.ts

https://cdn.chatenium.hu/CDN/stack/message.service.ts

Comment: The first question I have is: Where do you connect to the socket? In a public service, in a component?

Comment: A public service

Answer (score 0):

on logout disconnect your socket using the disconnect() method, which will close the socket when you logout and create a new connection when you log in, it is creating a new connection every time when you log in but it is not closing the old connection when you log out. use like,

```
 socket.disconnect();
```

Answer (score 0):

First important thing is to listen on the socket on a root service. Your your case, I think, you call the service multiple times. So multiple connection are open.

You show not your code... But I think your service will connect to the socket and handle incoming messages? Is so, then do **not** initialize the socket in every component you have. Better is make a `Subject` and bind all your components (+ child components) on it. So only the service receive the message and pushed them to the subscribed components.

On your main component, so `App.Component.ts` you handle the first connection and disconnect.

**On init you do:**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.mySocketService.connect(); // Call the connect method inside your service
  // Subscribe to messages
  this.mySub = this.mySocketService.getMessageSub().subscribe(data => console.log(data));
}
```

**On destroy you disconnect the service!**

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.mySocketService.disconnect();
}
```

Very important to do that only on the hightest component! Every time a child component will be hidden (router navigate, ngIf="false" and so on) the childs `ngOnDestroy` method will be called **and** then its `ngOnInit` again. And that can be your problem... Multi socket instances .

With the way I show here not a problem.

Comment: Still connects 3x, im gonna put the codes in my question. give me one sec

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, a component's service in nestjs was linked to another component.